# Firefox not behaving on card flip

Tags: html, angular, css, angular5

I created this animation for my web site
It should 
translate on Z axis (looks like it's getting smaller)
flip (show the back of the card)
translate back.

Here is the demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzfbaq

it works on Chrome but never shows the front of the flip in Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: It now show the front, but does a weird double flip at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving Flipping .You can use`transform:rotate(180deg);transition:1s`. Frequently these are used in onHover. So use those css while hovering the division. I will work in all browser.....

Comment: Thank you for your response. The flip is happening, it's done twice. As in the slackblitz above.  It will translateZ, then flip, translateZ back (it should stop there) but it does 2 extra flips.